# How to diagnose android crash report

Tags: android, react-native

I recently uploaded my first react-native android app to the google play store and there are quite a few of these crash reports in my google developer console. They are from many different device models and I am not able to reproduce any crash on my own device or emulator. Any idea where I can look to fix it? Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated!

```
com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: 
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp (ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:95)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackViewManagerSetter.setProperty (ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:129)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps (ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:48)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.updateProperties (ViewManager.java:36)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView (NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:227)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute (UIViewOperationQueue.java:150)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run (UIViewOperationQueue.java:770)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches (UIViewOperationQueue.java:855)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$1600 (UIViewOperationQueue.java:46)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$2.runGuarded (UIViewOperationQueue.java:813)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run (GuardedRunnable.java:21)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp (ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:83)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to  reproduce any crash on your own device or emulator. you just get the reported crash by looking at custom log in you crash reporting tools and try to fix it by those information.

Answer (score 0):

For crash reproduction, I like [Appsee](https://www.appsee.com/?cpnid=7010N000000hv6x). I save tons of time and money thanks to the crashed session recordings that they provide. I can catch crash issues that happen for individual users and quickly resolve the issue thanks to the level of detail in the recording.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Appsee.start() 
    return true
}
```